# How to make restful link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I need to generate link like

tasks/new/1

but my link_to generates link like

```
<%= link_to "", {:controller => "tasks", :action => "new", :pid => project.id } %>
```

tasks/new?pid=1

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

A link to "tasks/new/1" actually would not be restful. New links never specify their id, as you cannot know the id to be given out by the database. By convention the id behind a ressource belongs to that ressource, not a relation.

The Restful way would be

> /projects/1/tasks/new

You can achieve this via setting correct routing.

Have a look here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

And search for the heading nested resources.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have nested resources projects and tasks.

```
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_project_task(project) %>
```

This link should create path `/projects/1/tasks/new`

The short form is

```
<%= link_to 'New Task', [:new, @project, :task] %>
```

The routes file should have

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```

Comment: yeah you are right. I have nested resources projects and tasks it said undefined method `new_project_task' for #<#<Class:0xa7a1d40>:0xa1c5ef8>

Comment: @user1625602, you should mark answer as answered if it satisfied you